# Do not see onQuery callback triggered in NodeJS actions-on-google

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

### Overview

I am using the Node.js library [`actions-on-google`](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) client to build a smarthome action for the `Garage Door` device type. This action is deployed as a Cloud Function in GCP. I can confirm that the following works perfectly so far:

- Accounting linking with our OAuth flow
- Responding to sync intents (ie. `onSync()` in the client)
- Responding to execute intents (ie. `onExecute()` in the client)

### Problem

Despite that other callbacks (`onSync()` and `onExecute()`) work fine, we do not see any evidence of `onQuery()` being called no matter what. There aren't any errors showing in Stackdriver nor are their any logs being generated in Stackdriver under the "Google Actions" filter either.

We expect `onQuery()` to run when we ask Google Assistant things like *is the garage door open?* and *is Matt's Door closed?*

- We tried removing `async` to see if the call was hanging
- We tried removing `headers` in the lambda
- We tried removing all other code and redploying to isolate `onQuery()`

### Code

The following code shows the simple `onQuery()` callback. `onExecute()` and `onSync` code has been removed for clarity.

```js
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {smarthome} = require('actions-on-google');

const app = smarthome({
  jwt: require('./XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX.json'),
  debug: true,
});

//
// Note: Removed onSync() and onExecute() for clarity
//

app.onQuery(async (body, headers) => {

  // Expecting to see these logging statements in
  // Stackdriver like we do for onExecute() and 
  // onSync() ... but nothing ever shows up.
  
 console.info('=== onQuery.body', body);
 console.info('=== onQuery.headers', headers);

  // We have hardcoded the following ID and a "closed" 
  // state. It matches a valid device ID to the testing 
  // account we are using.

  return {
    requestId: body.requestId,
    payload: {
      devices: {
        '2489e4a92799728292b8d5a8b1c9d177': {
          on: true,
          online: true,
          openPercent: 0,
        }
      }
    }
  };
});

exports.smarthome = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

We considered the possibility that the JSON returned in the call to `onSync()` might be missing a trait or something that prevents it from responding to a query intent properly but we have not been able to identify anything that might be incorrect or missing. Here is the JSON payload returned from `onSync()`:

```js
{
 "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
 "payload": {
  "agentUserId": "1836.15267389",
  "devices": [{
   "id": "1234",
   "type": "action.devices.types.GARAGE",
   "traits": [
    "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
   ],
   "name": {
    "defaultNames": ["Smart Garage Door"],
    "name": "Matt's Door",
    "nicknames": ["Matt's Door"]
   },
   "willReportState": true,
   "attributes": {
    "openDirection": [
     "UP",
     "DOWN"
    ]
   },
   "deviceInfo": {
    "manufacturer": "ABC Corp",
    "model": "test",
    "hwVersion": "1.0",
    "swVersion": "1.0"
   }
  }]
 }
}
```

### Expected Result

We expect Google Assistant to respond with **"Garage door is closed"** or some other equivalent. Instead, we receive **"Sorry, I can't reach Matt's Door right now. Please try again."**

Comment: Is this potentially a naming issue? If it had a generic nickname like `Garage Door` would it work?

Comment: @NickFelker - it definitely was an issue with the `name` in the JSON returned from a sync intent. Ultimately, I ended up using something like the code below and the action started responding to query intents as I expect. Answering my own question in case others bump into this!

Comment: Oh... and thanks @NickFelker for pointing out my mistake. :) Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here in case anyone else has this trouble. The reason why my action was handling the SYNC and EXECUTE intents but not the QUERY intent came down to what default/user names I assigned each device in the SYNC response.

Ultimately, I started using the following and my action began responding to QUERY intents as expected again:

```
...

name: {
  defaultNames: ['Garage Door'],
  name: door.name,
  nicknames: [door.name, 'Garage Door']
},

...
```

where `door.name` is a name which is set by the user and is returned by an API call.